# When to use subscript and when to use index?

Tags: matrices, notation, index-notation

I'm learning math and machine learning by myself, and I get confused when I see that some matrices are indexed by subscript whereas some are indexed by index. For example, the following Bellman equation is given by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfHX2hHRMVQ&list=PL7-jPKtc4r78-wCZcQn5IqyuWhBZ8fOxT&index=2) at around 39 minutes

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm v &= R+\gamma P\mathrm v\\
\begin{bmatrix}v(1)\\v(2)\\\vdots\\ v(n)\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}R_1\\R_2\\\vdots\\ R_n\end{bmatrix}+\gamma \begin{bmatrix}P_{11} & P_{12} & \cdots &P_{1n}\\P_{21} & P_{22} & \cdots &P_{2n}\\\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\ P_{n1} & P_{n2} & \cdots &P_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v(1)\\v(2)\\\vdots\\ v(n)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

why does it use $\mathrm v(1)$ rather than $\mathrm v_1$? And $R_1$ rather than $R(1)$? All I can see is that $R$ is capitalized whereas $\mathrm v$ is not, but I don't understand what on earth makes them different from each other. Please help me get this straight completely, thanks in advance.

Comment: They both mean essentially the same thing.  One notation may be preferred in some areas while the other notation preferred in other areas.  The important thing is for it to be unambiguous what is meant in the context and to avoid having overused the notation to mean different things simultaneously.  For example, if I have a collection of matrices, I may choose to refer to them as "the first matrix", "the second matrix" and so on and may label them as such using a subscript notation as $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$, but then to refer to the first row first column entry of the first matrix...

Comment: ...it may get a bit convoluted, being notated perhaps as $(A_1)_{1,1}$.  For this reason, I might have chosen to use the index notation instead, or perhaps a left-subscript or superscript with parentheses (*to distinguish from powers*), etc..., maybe as $A^{(1)}_{1,1}$.  When writing, it helps to quickly remind people of what the notation intends near the start or just before the first time it is used in case it is unusual or in case alternatives for that notation exist.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for answering. Did you suggest that there is no certain mathematical convention lying in here, all is about personal preference?

Comment: It might be that the author is using the notation to indicate that $v$ is being thought of as a function.

Comment: @amd Thanks for answering. This makes a lot of sense.